# How do I pick an array position when pressing a key for example a number from 1 to 5?

Tags: java, arrays

When I run the program it shows me on the first values on the list which is the one with the [0] here is my array code:

```
KeyStroke[] clientsDetails = new KeyStroke[5];
clientsDetails[0] = new KeyStroke(9,"OX5BJM","Peter",2039489);
clientsDetails[1] = new KeyStroke(12,"OX1BOL","Kim",2434587);
clientsDetails[2] = new KeyStroke(67,"OX2VBN","Patrick",2233842);
clientsDetails[3] = new KeyStroke(34,"OX2XHB","Liam",2432340);
clientsDetails[4] = new KeyStroke(54,"OX3BUN","Bob",2234098);
```

And here is the code to support the array:

```
if(input.matches("S")){


    System.out.println("Enter an array postion from 1 to 4 to show paitient's details");

    number1 = enterNumber0.nextInt(); 

    System.out.println("Name: " +clientsDetails[0].nameLable);
    System.out.println("Age: " +clientsDetails[0].howOld);
    System.out.println("Postcode: " +clientsDetails[0].postcode);
    System.out.println("Phone Number: " + clientsDetails[0].cellPhoneNumber);


    number2 = enterNumber1.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Name: " +clientsDetails[1].nameLable);
    System.out.println("Age: " +clientsDetails[1].howOld);
    System.out.println("Postcode: " +clientsDetails[1].postcode);
    System.out.println("Phone Number: " + clientsDetails[1].cellPhoneNumber);


    number3 = enterNumber2.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Name: " +clientsDetails[2].nameLable);
    System.out.println("Age: " +clientsDetails[2].howOld);
    System.out.println("Postcode: " +clientsDetails[2].postcode);
    System.out.println("Phone Number: " + clientsDetails[2].cellPhoneNumber);


    number4 = enterNumber1.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Name: " +clientsDetails[3].nameLable);
    System.out.println("Age: " +clientsDetails[3].howOld);
    System.out.println("Postcode: " +clientsDetails[3].postcode);
    System.out.println("Phone Number: " + clientsDetails[3].cellPhoneNumber);


}
```

Help will be greatly appreciated this is the last bit of my work that I'm stuck on. I have no teacher to advice this for me as to why I added a question on this forum I hope nobody gets offended.

Comment: Do you want to only print the patient details for the person at the index specified by the user?

Comment: Yes I do thank you for reading my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `enterNumber0` is a Scanner that is already created, we can do something like this:

```
// Populate the array
KeyStroke[] clientsDetails = new KeyStroke[]{
    new KeyStroke(9,"OX5BJM","Peter",2039489),
    new KeyStroke(12,"OX1BOL","Kim",2434587),
    new KeyStroke(67,"OX2VBN","Patrick",2233842),
    new KeyStroke(34,"OX2XHB","Liam",2432340),
    new KeyStroke(54,"OX3BUN","Bob",2234098)
}
```

Not 100% sure what `input` does here, so I've kept this part. Also note that we fetch the ID from the user non-zero-indexed, so we have to subtract 1 to all the values. You also seem to have misunderstood how to use this value to return the correct client details. You use this value as the index in the array.

```
if (input.matches("S")) {
    System.out.println("Enter an array postion from 1 to 5 to show paitient's details");

    int number = enterNumber0.nextInt();

    if (number >= 1 && number <= 5) {
        System.out.println("Name: " +clientsDetails[number - 1].nameLable);
        System.out.println("Age: " +clientsDetails[number - 1].howOld);
        System.out.println("Postcode: " +clientsDetails[number - 1].postcode);
        System.out.println("Phone Number: " + clientsDetails[number - 1].cellPhoneNumber);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use matches which can accept an integer from `1 to 5`:

```
String number = enterNumber0.nextLine(); 
if(number.matches("[1-5]")){
    int index = Integer.parseInt(input) - 1;
    //use this index to get the value from your array

    System.out.println("Name: " +clientsDetails[index ].nameLable);
    System.out.println("Age: " +clientsDetails[index ].howOld);
    System.out.println("Postcode: " +clientsDetails[index ].postcode);
    System.out.println("Phone Number: " + clientsDetails[index ].cellPhoneNumber);
}
```

---

**Note** `-1`, because the array start from 0.